# (First C Program / Hello World) Keep getting Syntax Error

Tags: c

This is my current code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
void print_hello() {
    printf("Hello n10321234, welcome to BSB211");
}
    
int main() {
    print_hello();
    return 0;
}
```

However I keep getting the following errors when I compile and run the .exe:

> ./print_hello: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token ('
>
> ./print_hello: line 3: `void print_hello(){'

For compiling I used `gcc print_hello.c -o print_hello` and to run I use `./print_hello`

Comment: Can you call print_hello() after int main(){...}

Comment: Its for homework, and that is the test driver structure they gave us, that we need to follow.

Comment: This is a course in C in 2020 that uses `int main()`?!  Oy vey.

Comment: Since about 1990 (probably a few years before that), that should be `void print_hello(void)` and `int main(void)`.  Do not rely on conventions that exist only to support legacy code from past decades (and, sadly, last Tuesday as well).

Comment: @WilliamPursell This might be changed in the upcoming C2x standard, so writing `(void)` will become a legacy syntax and `()` will be equivalent to `(void)`. So this might be a 2020 course preparing people for C2x. Make sense actually.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. I compiled and run it successfully.

What happened is you've accidentally copied print_hello.c to print_hello. You're running this file as a script and get a script error. please make sure you compile correctly before running print_hello.

You can try to delete print_hello then run your gcc again.

This is what happens when I try to run the code as a script(exactly the same error)

```
>./hello.c
./hello.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hello.c: line 3: `void print_hello() {'
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be correct. I ran it on my machine and works fine.

I also ran it on ideone and it works fine.

Try reinstalling/updating your gcc. Maybe that will help.

Alternatively, you can create an Ubuntu Virtual Machine and try it there.